# where can I find the documentation for wix custom actions

Tags: wix

We are submitting our application to Microsoft for Windows Logo Program and they require us to provide documentation on every customActions in the installer.

We can provide documentation for the customActions we added, but there is a whole bunch automatically added by wix installer. I am trying online search but I couldn't find a reliable one for wix. Even the wix documentation doesn't talk about the customActions or may be I'm missing something.

Can you point me to the right direction?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look at the CHM files installed with WiX - you'll find the necessary information in there.